# How to Load Test a Web Service From a Text File of URLs

Tags: stress-testing

I am working on load testing a web service where request are of the form:

```
GET http://host/my/app/some-data
```

Where `some-data` is a string that serves as input to the logic behind the service.  Now I have 1 million urls with random values for `some-data`, and now I want to try to simulate load with those 1M urls.

```
GET http://host/my/app/some-data_1
GET http://host/my/app/some-data_2 
...
GET http://host/my/app/some-data_1e6
```

I dont know how to do that and have not made any substantial progress towards the goal. How do I do this?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Well, problem described, no real approach so far besides ab and wrk, etc..  How do you want me to ask that?

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty trivial task for good load testing software, so I'm curious why you haven't had any success. You didn't mention what level of load you are trying to test - if you are looking for a very high level of concurrency, then that may rule out many of the tools.

So: I'd start by researching some load testing tools that can handle the level of concurrency you need and are within your budget.

Comment: Thanks CMerill. I'm not familiar with good load testing software.  I have a copy of ab and wrk, I've also hear Jmeter is good and possibly locust.io.  What would be great is to understand what would be an effective way to set up aggressive stress testing, say from 5 client boxes to 3 app boxes and get a combined, summarized report, with a dev and ops friendly tool.  This would be super useful in my org.